# MYSQL INSERT INTO ERROR

Tags: mysql, insert-into

i keep getting  error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '."LTTA3101","1","03-JAN-07"),
("SK3127","LTCPF502","5","03-JAN-07")' at line 17

```
INSERT INTO sales
(cust_id,prod_id,quanitity,date_of_sale)
values
("MH3367
","DTHP7710","1","01-OCT-06"),
("GM4632","DTCP2109","4","08-OCT-06"),
("GM2581","LTTA3101","1","10-OCT-06"),
("GM4632","LTCPF502","2","28-0CT-06"),
("KM4673","LTCPC505","4","04-NOV-06"),
("MH3367","LTPBMZ36","3","22-NOV-06
"),
("KS2169","LTTA0338","4","14-DEC-06"),
("AS3485","DJHP1280","5","16-DEC-06"),
("KM4637","DJEPR180","5","18-DEC-06"),
("GM2581","A1HPF380","8","19-DEC-06"),
("GM4632","A1LX5470","9","22-DEC-06"),
("AS3485","DTHP7710","1","23-DEC-06"),
("SK3127","DTCP2109","5","24-DEC-06"),
("AS3485"."LTTA3101","1","03-JAN-07"),
("SK3127","LTCPF502","5","03-JAN-07");
```

can  anyone  help?

Thanks..

Comment: after correct .(dot) mistake what error coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO sales
(cust_id,prod_id,qty,date_of_sale)
values
("MH3367","DTHP7710","1","2006-10-01"),
("GM4632","DTCP2109","4","2006-10-02"),
("GM2581","LTTA3101","1","2006-10-03"),
("GM4632","LTCPF502","2","2006-10-04"),
("KM4673","LTCPC505","4","2006-11-04"),
("MH3367","LTPBMZ36","3","2006-11-22"),
("KS2169","LTTA0338","4","2006-12-09"),
("AS3485","DJHP1280","5","2006-12-16"),
("KM4637","DJEPR180","5","2006-12-18"),
("GM2581","A1HPF380","8","2006-12-19"),
("GM4632","A1LX5470","9","2006-12-20"),
("AS3485","DTHP7710","1","2006-12-21"),
("SK3127","DTCP2109","5","2006-12-30"),
("AS3485","LTTA3101","1","2007-01-07"),
("SK3127","LTCPF502","5","2007-01-07");
```

Comment: sorry no  just a tad confused, sorry .

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''cust_id','prod_id','quanitity','date_of_sale')
VALUES
("MH3367","DTHP7710","1' at line 1

Comment: edit done to answer chg'ing formats, removing the '.'  ..... works 15 rows inserted

Comment: 15 rows inserted see answer again

Answer (score 0):

You have a " . " instead of a comma on the 19th line of your query, the first character mentioned in the quote is usually the issue when you get a MySQL Syntax error.

Comment: is their anything else it could be?